# {"a" : 1 } at Chrome cause SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, object

I met a problem at chrome. 
[image: Is there some bug in chrome?]

Why it cause a syntaxError? I have tried it in nodejs, it is ok.

Comment: In case you write `{a:1}` the `a` is interpreted as label in a block context and `1` is returned as a value following the label. Since `"a"` is not a valid identifier it can't be label and you got `SyntaxError`

Answer (score 8):

In the context in which you are running (and the Chrome and Node REPLs have different default contexts) it, the `{` character starts a **block**, not an object literal.

You can't follow a string with a `:` in a block.

If you were to say `({ "a": 1 })` you would change the context so it would be an object literal.

Comment: It will be great if you add @vadim's comment to your answer.